# How to store text field value in to a variable for further use of it in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, variables, text, input

initialized a variable "input" and i want store the text in to it. so that i can perform search operation using that variable. by the below code it is not taking the variable input. thanks inadvance. please anyone help me

String input;

```
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            input = jt.getText(); // problem occurs here
            jl.setText(input);  
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error message? Can you validate `jt` having text when `jb`'s listener is called?

Comment: when you say problem, what exactly is happening?.

Comment: @Trobbins If he does not have text, would not he be getting an empty string which is still valid..

Comment: @Pavan you're correct, I phrased my question incorrectly. It was moreso a seed to have OP think about what `jt` contained / if it was instantiated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You say "problem occurs here". What problem? What is jb? what is jt? what is jl? what is the value of 'input' after 'input = jt.getText()' ?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** if you want to use the object anywhere of your program please declare it at the top of your program. Like that

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class MyExample {

    private JFrame frame;
    String input;
```

You shouldn't declare type of 'input' at out of an anonymous class. In this way, you have an error like 'The final local variable input cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type'. In order to avoid this error, please make sure that you write the code in this way,

```
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input = jt.getText();
                jl.setText(input);
            }
        });
```

So you can put the input into JLabel.

Comment: What if the OP wants to use the `input` value outside of the context of the inner class?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry, I might be wrong, I've created a new project for the question and tested it. But if I put 'String input' outside, it gives me an error so I've searched for the error and found that an anonymous class makes its own copy and puts the objects into its copy.  That's why the object you defined outside and the object that is inside are not the same object anymore.

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry I understand now. We should declare it at the top of program if we want to use it outside of inner class. I will edit my answer.